# Changing attribute dropdown to radio buttons

Tags: attributes

I was wondering if there was any way to change the attribute display from dropdown list to radio buttons.
I know that there are extension doing this but they are very expensive for a simple feature like this that for my opinion Magento should implement itself without any extensions.

Is there any simple way to achieve that ?

Comment: is it unclear to me what you're asking, can you provide us with a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the Dropdown options on a Configurable etc product then you can use this:
http://inchoo.net/magento/configurable-product-modification-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

It is not that easy, because a lot of JS is involved.

Magento renders the select fields one by one, after you chose an option, so you get only them for choice, which are available.

And yes, you can do this, by just reimplementing the JS and changing the templates.

I think you want to start here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this [extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher), it has what you are looking for and much more. You can add images for the buttons and change image depending on the attribute selected.

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up, but that extension does not turn the select into radio buttons. it turns them into clickable labels.

Comment: well i think that is an option for what is he looking...

Comment: Then +1 for the awesome extension recommendation :)